# I'm unable to see anything on Ubuntu Software

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I'm unable to see anything on Ubuntu Software Center.whenever i open Ubuntu Software center it just loads
forever,and it has nothing to with a bad connection what should i do?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?